# How to conditionally declare Bean when multiple profiles are not active?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my Spring-Boot-App I want to conditionally declare a Bean, depending on (un)loaded spring-profiles.

The conditon:

```
Profile "a" NOT loaded  
AND  
Profile "b" NOT loaded
```

My solution so far (which works):

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnExpression("#{!environment.getProperty('spring.profiles.active').contains('a') && !environment.getProperty('spring.profiles.active').contains('b')}")
    public MyBean myBean(){/*...*/}
```

Is there a more elegant (and shorter) way to explain this condition?
Especially I want to get rid of the usage of Spring Expression Language here.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Since Spring 5.1.4 (incorporated in Spring Boot 2.1.2) it is possible to use a profile expression inside profile string annotation. So:

In **Spring 5.1.4 (Spring Boot 2.1.2) and above** it is as easy as:

```
@Component
@Profile("!a & !b")
public class MyComponent {}
```

In **Spring 4.x and 5.0.x**:

There are many approaches for this Spring versions, each one of them has its pro's and con's. When there aren't many combinations to cover I personally like [@Stanislav answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429168/how-to-conditionally-declare-bean-when-multiple-profiles-are-not-active#answer-35433105) with the `@Conditional` annotation.

Other approaches can be found in this similar questions:

[Spring Profile - How to include AND condition for adding 2 profiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50181799/spring-profile-how-to-include-and-condition-for-adding-2-profiles)

[Spring: How to do AND in Profiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27055072/spring-how-to-do-and-in-profiles)

Comment: For this specific case (double negation), you need to make extra sure, that it's spring-core: 5.1.4+ / spring-boot: 2.1.2+, as there was a nasty bug up until those versions: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/22138

Comment: Can this have more than two profiles? I believe that should work correctly. For e.x.: "!a & !b & !c"

Answer (score 37):

If you have a single profile you could simply use a `@Profile` annotation with the not operator. It also accepts multiple profiles, but with the `OR` condition.

So, the alternative solution is to use a custom [`Condition`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Condition.html) with the [`@Conditional`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) annotation. Like so:

```
public class SomeCustomCondition implements Condition {
  @Override
  public boolean matches(ConditionContext context, AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {

    // Return true if NOT "a" AND NOT "b"
    return !context.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles("a") 
                  && !context.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles("b");
  }
}
```

And then annotate your method with it, like:

```
@Bean
@Conditional(SomeCustomCondition.class)
public MyBean myBean(){/*...*/}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like this approach. +1 for using `Condition`. I will just wait some time before I accept this answer. Maybe there comes another suggestion which is even more elegant ;-) (But I don't think so)

Comment: I tried same above but for some reason it's ignoring @Conditional annotation. Any suggestion?

Comment: acceptProfiles () is a vararg. We can specify multiple profiles at once like return !context.getEnvironment().acceptsProfiles("a", "b") ;

Answer (score 21):

I prefer this solution which is more verbose but still fine for two profiles only:

```
@Profile("!a")
@Configuration
public class NoAConfig {

    @Profile("!b")
    @Configuration
    public static class NoBConfig {
        @Bean
        public MyBean myBean(){
            return new MyBean();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately I don't have a shorter solution for you, but if it is suitable in your case to create the same beans for each profile, you may consider the following approach.

```
@Configuration
public class MyBeanConfiguration {

   @Bean
   @Profile("a")
   public MyBean myBeanForA() {/*...*/}

   @Bean
   @Profile("b")
   public MyBean myBeanForB() {/*...*/}

   @Bean
   @ConditionalOnMissingBean(MyBean.class)
   public MyBean myBeanForOthers() {/*...*/}

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this is not suitable for me. Let's say we have Profile `a` AND `b` loaded, then the `MyBean` is loaded twice in this case and usually we don't want this behaviour.   
The second thing is, that this is not a solution for my question. When both profiles are not loaded then the `MyBean` should not be declared, too.

Comment: Using `@ConditionalOnMissingBean` like this is dangerous. To be safe, it should only be used on auto-configuration classes

Comment: Thanks for your comments, guys. I used to using profiles as bunches of environment-related configuration properties, like 'dev', 'test', etc. Really, this approach cannot be used in case both profiles are loaded.

Comment: @AndyWilkinson could you please to explain why this approach is unsafe ?

Comment: @wakedeer Without the ordering guarantees that auto-configuration provides, the condition on `myBeanForOthers` may be evaluated before some other `@Bean` method that also defines a bean of type `MyBean`. This would leave you with two beans of type `MyBean`.

Answer (score 3):

A variant of [@Stanislav answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429168/how-to-conditionally-declare-bean-when-multiple-profiles-are-not-active#answer-35433105) which is a tiny bit more readable, for Spring versions up to 5.0.x / Spring Boot 2.0.x.

```
public class SomeCustomCondition implements Condition {
  @Override
  public boolean matches(final ConditionContext context, final AnnotatedTypeMetadata metadata) {
    final Environment environment = context.getEnvironment();

    // true if profile is NOT "a" AND NOT "b" AND NOT "c"
    return !environment.acceptsProfiles("a", "b", "c");
  }
}
```

For newer versions of Spring / Spring Boot, see the [f-CJ answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52860023/265954).