# How can i exclude spring bean from autowiring candidates for multiple profiles?

Tags: java, spring

I want to exclude bean from autowiring candidates if current profile is NOT one of array, like this:

```
@Component
@ActiveProfiles(value = {"!profile_1", "!profile_2"})
public class MyComponentImpl implements MyComponent

@Component
public class MyComponentDummy implements MyComponent
```

But when i'm trying to do it via @ActiveProfiles annotation that bean doesn't seem to be excluded and i'm getting `expected single matching bean but found 2`.

Am i missing something or it is impossible that way and must be done with something like

```
@ActiveProfiles(value = {"profile_3", "!profile_4", ... })
```

My spring version is 4.2.2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could be similar to query here [How to conditionally declare Bean when multiple profiles are not active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429168/how-to-conditionally-declare-bean-when-multiple-profiles-are-not-active)

On other hand I would recommend to do positive selection rather than negative elimination.
The "default" profile could be of helpful here.
Lets say you have multiple profiles - Profile1.. Profile5

And you do not want to create instance of bean if its Profile1 or Profile2

So you can annotate it with 
    @ActiveProfiles(value={"Profile3","Profile4","Profile5","default")

Comment: Yes, the question on your link is exactly the same, sorry