# Multiple negations in Spring's @Profile annotation

Tags: spring, spring-boot

In my code `@Profile({ "!a" })` excludes a bean from usage in profile `a`.
However if I specify `@Profile({ "!a", "!b" })` it still gets used in profile `b`.
Is there any way to exclude a bean from two profiles at the same time without specifying a whitelist for profiles?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally declare Bean when multiple profiles are not active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429168/how-to-conditionally-declare-bean-when-multiple-profiles-are-not-active)

Answer (score 1):

You can use logical operators and form an expression.
Example: `@Profile("!a & !b")`