# Autowire a specific bean given a profile

Tags: java, spring

I have 2 classes implementing InterfaceA

```
@Service("classA")
class ClassA implements InterfaceA

@Service("classB")
class ClassB implements InterfaceA
```

I need to load both beans.  In class C and D, though, I need to specify the bean that I need

```
class ClassC {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("classA")
    private InterfaceA interf;
}

class ClassD {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("classA")
    private InterfaceA interf;
}
```

However, I have 2 profiles, profile1 and profile2.  If i use -Dspring.profiles.active=profile1, I should be using qualifier "classA" for classC and classD.  If i use -Dspring.profiles.active=profile2, I should use "classB" as qualifier.  Also, another ClassE should always use classB regardless of the profile. Can you please advise how should I do it?

Comment: Can you explain your use case a bit further? It may help to determine a sensible solution if it's a little more concrete.

Comment: I have 2 deployment. One in a local server and another is in cloud.  I need to use classB in cloud cause it has different implementation with classA which is only for local server.

Comment: Then why are you needing to create both beans?

Comment: Cause there are implementations in ClassD that are used in both profiles so I need to make both beans available.

Comment: It sounds like you're making things unnecessarily complicated, but the way to do what you want is probably to have an `@Configuration` class with nested sub-configurations, each of which has a profile set on it and configures its beans specifically.

Comment: If i do the configuration, still how will i use it in ClassC and ClassD for a specific profile?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to conditionally declare Bean when multiple profiles are not active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35429168/how-to-conditionally-declare-bean-when-multiple-profiles-are-not-active)

Answer (score 1):

So this is how I did it.  I created a configuration class

```
@Configuration
public class ConfigClass {
    @Autowired
    private ClassB classB;

    @Profile("profile1")
    @Qualifier("myclass")
    @Bean
    private InterfaceA classAtProfile1() {return new ClassA();}

    @Profile("profile2")
    @Qualifier("myclass")
    @Bean
    private InterfaceA classAtProfile2() {return classB;}
}

class ClassA implements InterfaceA

@Service("classB")
class ClassB implements InterfaceA
```

This way, I can autowire InterfaceA based on profile

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("myclass")
private InterfaceA myclass;
```

While ClassE can still refer to classB

```
@Component
public class ClassE {
    @Autowired
    ClassB classB;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Define 2 configuration java files:

```
class ClassA implements InterfaceA

class ClassB implements InterfaceA
```

Sample config file 1:

**Profile1Config.java**

```
 @Configuration
 @Profile("profile1")
 public class Profile1Config {
    @Bean
    public InterfaceA interfaceA() {
       return new ClassA();
    }
 }
```

Sample config file 2:

**Profile1Config.java**

```
 @Configuration
 @Profile("profile2")
 public class Profile2Config {
    @Bean
    public InterfaceA interfaceA() {
       return new ClassB();
    }
 }
```

And wherever you want to use this:

```
class ClassC {
   @Autowired
   private InterfaceA interf;
}

class ClassD {
    @Autowired
    private InterfaceA interf;
}
```

Key point to note:
1. @Qualifier was not required.
2. @Profile is mentioned at the Java Configuration class.
3. @Service was removed from classA and classB rather defined in Config* classes  now.