Is it possible to conveniently override/remove an annotation from a @Component annotated class when running a SpringBootTest?
I have @Component named RequestInterceptor, which is also annotated with @RestartScope. Problem is, since I'm running integration tests with SpringBootTest and clearing contexts with @DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.BEFORE_EACH_TEST_METHOD - I'm still fiddling with it), whenever a test bumps into a bean method called from the RequestInterceptor, I get the following exception thrown:
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.flyway-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayProperties': Could not bind properties to 'FlywayProperties' : prefix=spring.flyway, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@55fbebba has been closed already
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindException: Error creating bean with name 'spring.flyway-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.flyway.FlywayProperties': Could not bind properties to 'FlywayProperties' : prefix=spring.flyway, ignoreInvalidFields=false, ignoreUnknownFields=true; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: org.springframework.web.context.support.GenericWebApplicationContext@55fbebba has been closed already
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1014)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909)

If I get rid of the @RestartScope annotation, everything goes back to normal and all tests are executed correctly. Since I can't alter this class and need to test it (and all other controllers, but the interceptor gets in the way), is there a way I can override only this annotation? If not, what would be a good alternative for my case?

Since you round down the problem to the @RestartScope you could create two of these interceptors and annotate them so one works with production and the other with tests. Check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/q/35429168/460557 the reason im suggesting two classes is only because of the requestscope annotation since you can't disable it at runtime (afaik)

@JorgeCampos in this case, would it be better to run the tests without DirtiesContext? I know it is an anti-pattern on unit tests, but I'm unsure on how to proceed with integration tests.

If you do as suggested, yes you would not need DirtiesContext

For tests I would define my own TestConfig
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
    @Primary
    @Bean //default singleton scope
    public RequestInterceptor requestInterceptorForTest {
        return new RequestInterceptor();
    }
}

then only apply this TestConfig for the tests needed with @Import
@Import(TestConfig.class)
public class FooTest {
    //...
}

